# Python: Export Messages as .msg using pywin32.client

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I am hitting a road block with exporting outlook messages as .msg files. I'm not sure on how to accomplish this task. I have a program that currently reads the email and exports the attachments and once it completes it moves the message to a processed folder so I can keep track of what has been completed. I need to add a function that exports the entire email itself to a folder on the local machine. Has anyone accomplished this using pywin32.client?

Here is the program as it stands now. (excuse the mess its still in progress)

```
import os
import win32com.client
import csv
import datetime
from random import randint

ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER = "C:\\EMAILS"
LOG_PATH = 'C:\\EMAILS\\log.csv'
COUNTER = 1
SUBFOLDER_LIST = ["TEST"]
UPLOAD_LIST = 'C:\\EMAILS\\logupload%d.csv' % randint(2,150000)


def ExportMessages (Folder, item):
    #No IDEA!
    pass

def process_attachment(sender, subject, attachment, messagedate):
  """
  :param sender:
  :param subject:
  :param attachment:
  :param messagedate:
  """
  global count
  count = 0
  try:
    filepath = os.path.join(ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER, "RAN-%dSEN-%sSUB-%s%s" % (randint(2,100000),str(sender), str(subject), attachment))
    count = count +1
    print "Trying", filepath
    open(filepath, "r")
    os.remove(filepath)
  except IOError:
    pass

  try:
    attachment.SaveAsFile(filepath)
    row = [messagedate, sender, subject, count]
    row2 = [messagedate, sender, subject, filepath]
    w = csv.writer(csv_file)
    w2 = csv.writer(csv_file2)
    w.writerow(row)
    w2.writerow(row2)
  except:
    pass

def move_message_fail(message, folder):
  """
  :param message:
  :param folder:
  """
  print "Moving:", message.Subject
  proc_folder = folder.Folders("Failed")
  message.Move(proc_folder)

def move_message(folder, message):
  """
  :param folder:
  :param message:
  """
  print "Moving:", message.Subject
  proc_folder = folder.Folders("Processed")
  message.Move(proc_folder)

def process_message(message, folder):
  """
  :param message:
  :param folder:
  """
  global vin_num
  vin_num = ''
  print "Message:", message.Subject
  vin = message.Subject
  sender = message.SenderName
  if folder == SUBFOLDER_LIST[0]:
    for i in vin.split(' '):
        if '-' in i:
            vin_num = i
    if vin_num:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        messagedate = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
        attachments = message.Attachments
        for n_attachment in range(attachments.Count):
            attachment = attachments.Item(n_attachment + 1)
            #if attachment.Type == win32com.client.constants.CdoFileData:
            process_attachment(sender, vin_num, attachment, messagedate)
            #message.Update()
            move_message(folder, message, up_folder)
    else:
        move_message_fail(message, folder)
  else:
    vin_num = vin.split(' ')[1]
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    messagedate = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    attachments = message.Attachments
    for n_attachment in range(attachments.Count):
        attachment = attachments.Item(n_attachment + 1)
        #if attachment.Type == win32com.client.constants.CdoFileData:
        process_attachment(sender, vin_num, attachment, messagedate)
        #message.Update()
        move_message(folder, message, up_folder)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  csv_file = open(LOG_PATH, "ab")
  csv_file2 = open(UPLOAD_LIST, "wb")
  for i in SUBFOLDER_LIST:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    one_folder = outlook.Folders(1)
    two_folder = one_folder.Folders("Inbox")
    three_folder = two_folder.Folders(i)
    messages = three_folder.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()
    while message:
      process_message(message, i)
      ExportMessages(three_folder, message)
      message = messages.GetNext()
```

Comment: I have 3 outlook profiles (3 different email accounts) setup. So how to choose which profile's (account's) Inbox to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call MailItem.SaveAs and pass olMsg or olMsgUnicode as the second (Format) parameter.

Comment: You can use Application.CreateItemFromTemplate, but keep in mind that Outlook creates a new item using the existing MSG file as a template, so not all properties are copied. You can use Redemption and its RDOSession.GetMessageFrommsgFile (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) to directly open an MSG file.

Comment: I have 3 outlook profiles (3 different email accounts) setup. So how to choose which profile's (account's) Inbox to use?

Comment: @user5155835 - start a new thread. Do not hijack an existing thread that has nothing to do with your question.