# Saving to .msg file in Python, or alternatively, sending mail to the file system

Tags: python, email

I'm using the `emails` library to send mail, but I also need to save it as `.msg` file. I've done some research and also read the msg format specification and stumbled upon [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423657/1453822) that shows how to send mail to the file system in `C#` and I was wondering if it was possible in Python as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible and easy. Let's assume that `msg` is a previously composed message with all headers and content, and that you want to write it to the file object `out`. You just need:

```
gen = email.generator.Generator(out)  # create a generator
gen.flatten(msg)   # write the message to the file object
```

Full example:

```
import email

# create a simple message
msg = email.mime.text.MIMEText('''This is a simple message.
And a very simple one.''')
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple message'
msg['From'] = 'sender@sending.domain'
msg['To'] = 'rcpt@receiver.domain'

# open a file and save mail to it
with open('filename.elm', 'w') as out:
    gen = email.generator.Generator(out)
    gen.flatten(msg)
```

The content of filename.elm is:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Simple message
From: sender@sending.domain
To: rcpt@receiver.domain

This is a simple message.
And a very simple one.
```

Comment: Thanks. I created an `email` instance from my `emails` instance and it worked, but is there a way to save it as `msg` instead of `eml`? I've tried to change `with open('filename.elm', 'w')` to `with open('filename.msg', 'w')` but (as expected) outlook couldn't open that file.

Comment: @DeepSpace The msg format is a binary proprietary format . The only reasonable way to use it is through outlook automation. Searching for `[python] outlook msg file` in SO gave [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18066180/) that could give you some hints. I cannot help you further because I haven't been using outlook for decades.

Answer (score 1):

it is doable in Python,  I tried the following code which saves outlook messages as .msg in a folder.
Note:make sure that outlook has write access to the destination folder, by default the destination folder is the location of Python script

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") 
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.items
for msg in messages:
  name = msg.subject
  name = str(name)
  name = name + ".msg"
  msg.saveas(name)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution only works on Windows development environments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.
There are modules for these purposes and it is called [MSG PY](https://pypi.org/project/independentsoft.msg).
For example:

```
from independentsoft.msg import Message
from independentsoft.msg import Recipient
from independentsoft.msg import ObjectType
from independentsoft.msg import DisplayType
from independentsoft.msg import RecipientType
from independentsoft.msg import MessageFlag
from independentsoft.msg import StoreSupportMask

message = Message()

recipient1 = Recipient()
recipient1.address_type = "SMTP"
recipient1.display_type = DisplayType.MAIL_USER
recipient1.object_type = ObjectType.MAIL_USER
recipient1.display_name = "John Smith"
recipient1.email_address = "John@domain.com"
recipient1.recipient_type = RecipientType.TO

recipient2 = Recipient()
recipient2.address_type = "SMTP"
recipient2.display_type = DisplayType.MAIL_USER
recipient2.object_type = ObjectType.MAIL_USER
recipient2.display_name = "Mary Smith"
recipient2.email_address = "Mary@domain.com"
recipient2.recipient_type = RecipientType.CC

message.subject = "Test"
message.body = "Body text"
message.display_to = "John Smith"
message.display_cc = "Mary Smith"
message.recipients.append(recipient1)
message.recipients.append(recipient2)
message.message_flags.append(MessageFlag.UNSENT)
message.store_support_masks.append(StoreSupportMask.CREATE)

message.save("e:\\message.msg")
```

Comment: Note as per  the module creator's website (https://www.independentsoft.de/msgpy/index.html) this isn't free software. Installing via PIP gives you an 'evaluation version' with a 30 day expiry.

Answer (score 1):

As per python's official examples - https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html it is possible to save an email as a .msg file, and then later on load it.

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.parser import BytesParser
from email import policy

# Create the base text message.
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner"
msg['From'] = Address("Pepé Le Pew", "pepe", "example.com")
msg['To'] = (Address("Penelope Pussycat", "penelope", "example.com"),
             Address("Fabrette Pussycat", "fabrette", "example.com"))
msg.set_content("""\
Salut!

Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

[1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

--Pepé
""")

# Make a local copy of what we are going to send.
with open('outgoing.msg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(msg))

# Load local copy of email
with open('outgoing.msg', 'rb') as fp:
    loaded_msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
```

Comment: The output of this example cannot be opened natively by MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this (but the question is not very clear, and parts of it are in the comments) is:

```
 import email
 from email.message import EmailMessage
```

If `msg` is something created using `msg = EmailMessage()` and populated with appropriate calls (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) then `msg` can be saved using

```
with open('mymessage.msg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(bytes(msg))
```

and that file can be recovered using:

```
 with open('mymessage.msg', 'rb') as fp:
       msg = email.message_from_binary_file(fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to complete this using Win32Com...

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items

message.SaveAs(os.path.join("output folder", (message.Subject + ".msg")))
```