# How to save HTML email as an outlook file using Python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

Someone created a nice email template in outlook and sent it to me for automation.

I opened the email in HTML, and used that HTML to recreate the exact email images, formatting and all.

I can send this email out just fine, but I was then asked if I could save all the email files in a folder so that one could click on it and have it open up in their outlook (a .msg file).

I can save my email as an .mht and .elm file, but neither will open in outlook.

Seemed like an easy request...

```
  msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')...
  ...      
  ...
  msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

  msgText = MIMEText('no alternative text version')
  msgAlternative.attach(msgText)


  msgText = MIMEText("""
  ...
  ...#too much going on here to paste. formatting and attaching images.
  ...
```

The part where I can successfully save this as .mht file:

```
  with open("C:/LOCAL/test/"+var+'.mht', 'w+') as out:
        gen = email.generator.Generator(out)
        gen.flatten(msgRoot)
```

Is there an easy way to just save this as the .msg file so that it opens in the client?  Like a preloaded email file.  You open it, it's addressed etc... just need to hit send.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving to .msg file in Python, or alternatively, sending mail to the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235626/saving-to-msg-file-in-python-or-alternatively-sending-mail-to-the-file-system)

Comment: Save it on your Computer folder or Outlook folder?

Comment: Save it to my computer folder

Answer (score 3):

*Work with [SaveAs Method [MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210279(v=office.11)) with [OlSaveAsType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olsaveastype?view=outlook-pia) to get the correct file format*

*Example*

```
import win32com.client

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox)
SubFolder = Inbox.Folders["folder name"]

for Item in SubFolder.Items:

    try:
        Item.SaveAs("D:\\Temp\\email.msg", 3)  # OlSaveAsType 3
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

---

***[OlSaveAsType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olsaveastype?view=outlook-pia)***

---

> ```
> +--------------+----+---------------------------------------+
> | olDoc        |  4 | Microsoft Office Word format (.doc)   |
> | olHTML       |  5 | HTML format (.html)                   |
> | olICal       |  8 | iCal format (.ics)                    |
> | olMHTML      | 10 | MIME HTML format (.mht)               |
> | olMSG        |  3 | Outlook message format (.msg)         |
> | olMSGUnicode |  9 | Outlook Unicode message format (.msg) |
> | olRTF        |  1 | Rich Text format (.rtf)               |
> | olTemplate   |  2 | Microsoft Outlook template (.oft)     |
> | olTXT        |  0 | Text format (.txt)                    |
> | olVCal       |  7 | VCal format (.vcs)                    |
> | olVCard      |  6 | VCard format (.vcf)                   |
> +--------------+----+---------------------------------------+
> ```